# eloquent laravel: How to get a row count from a ->get()

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to use this collection to count rows.

```
$wordlist = \DB::table('wordlist')->where('id', '<=', $correctedComparisons)
                ->get();
```

I have tried `adding->count()` but didn't work. I have tried doing `count($wordlist)`. I'm not really sure what to do without needing a second request as `a->count()` method.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

**Answer has been updated**

`count` is a Collection method. The query builder returns an array. So in order to get the count, you would just count it like you normally would with an array:

```
$wordCount = count($wordlist);
```

If you have a wordlist model, then you can use Eloquent to get a Collection and then use the Collection's `count` method. Example:

```
$wordlist = Wordlist::where('id', '<=', $correctedComparisons)->get();
$wordCount = $wordlist->count();
```

There is/was a discussion on having the query builder return a collection here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10478

However as of now, the query builder always returns an array.

Edit: As linked above, the query builder now returns a collection (not an array). As a result, what JP Foster was trying to do initially will work:

```
$wordlist = \DB::table('wordlist')->where('id', '<=', $correctedComparisons)
            ->get();
$wordCount = $wordlist->count();
```

However, as indicated by Leon in the comments, if all you want is the count, then querying for it directly is much faster than fetching an entire collection and then getting the count. In other words, you can do this:

```
// Query builder
$wordCount = \DB::table('wordlist')->where('id', '<=', $correctedComparisons)
            ->count();

// Eloquent
$wordCount = Wordlist::where('id', '<=', $correctedComparisons)->count();
```

Comment: It is quicker to access count() directly with a where clause than returning the whole collection. If this was a count of your entire user table for example, it could be return 1m results just to count them, and that would use a lot of resources.

Comment: For me query builder gives count 1 even if there are more results. Using same queryBuilder I return other results.

Comment: it works as expected with db:table

Answer (score 141):

Direct get a count of row

**Using Eloquent**

```
 //Useing Eloquent
 $count = Model::count();    

 //example            
 $count1 = Wordlist::count();
```

**Using query builder**

```
 //Using query builder
 $count = \DB::table('table_name')->count();

 //example
 $count2 = \DB::table('wordlist')->where('id', '<=', $correctedComparisons)->count();
```

Comment: This should be on top <3

Comment: Eloquent one is more graceful

Answer (score 42):

Its better to access the count with the laravels count method

```
$count = Model::where('status','=','1')->count();
```

or

```
$count = Model::count();
```

Answer (score 7):

also, you can fetch all data and count in the blade file.
for example:

your code in the controller

```
$posts = Post::all();
return view('post', compact('posts'));
```

your code in the blade file.

```
{{ $posts->count() }}
```

finally, you can see the total of your posts.

Comment: Definitely don't do this whenever you only need the number of records in a table. `Post::all()` will load the entire post table in a collection and then count the number of records in the instantiated collection, resulting in very poor performance when dealing with large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

//controller `$count = Post::count();   return view('post', compact('count'));`

//blade `{{$count}}`

or
//controller `$posts = Post::all(); return view('post', compact('posts'));`

//blade`{{count($posts)}}`