# Show number of registers in a table in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to show the number of records in a table, and then show them, something like:  The number of records is: ((number) this with laravel 5.

I have this function in the model of my table.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ingrediente extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','proveedor'];
    public function mostrar(){
        $result = Ingrediente::count();
            return $result; 
    }
}
```

And this is my index.

```
 <div class="card-body">

    <a href="{{ route('ingredientes.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Ingrediente</a>

    @foreach($ingredientes as $ingrediente)
    <small id="total" class="form-text text-muted">Hay un total de {{$ingrediente->mostrar}} ingredientes en el sistema.
    </small>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to showing the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Im Sorry man, edited.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in  ....

Comment: You have obviously not posted ALL of the code.

Comment: When you have an error like that, you are supposed to add it to your question.

Comment: First, you missing **@endforeach** after **</small>**.
Second, what suppose `mostrar()` return exactly?

Comment: $result = Ingrediente::count(); a count of the table ingrediente

Comment: I guess understanding what you need to do. I'll answer it now.

Comment: @BrayanR Hi just go through this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676576/eloquent-laravel-how-to-get-a-row-count-from-a-get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller:

```
public function index() {
    $ingredientes = Ingrediente::all();
    return view('your-view-path', compact('ingredientes'));
}
```

In view:

```
<small id="total" class="form-text text-muted">Hay un total de {{$ingredientes->count()}} ingredientes en el sistema.
    </small>
```

OR

```
<small id="total" class="form-text text-muted">Hay un total de {{count($ingredientes)}} ingredientes en el sistema.
    </small>
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $ingredientes = Ingrediente::all();
    return view('your-view-path', compact('$ingredientes'));
}
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ingrediente extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','proveedor'];
}
```

View:

```
<div class="card-body">

    <a href="{{ route('ingredientes.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Ingrediente</a>

    @foreach($ingredientes as $ingrediente)
    <p>{{$ingrediente->nombre}}</p>
    @endforeach

    <small id="total" class="form-text text-muted">Hay un total de {{$ingredientes->count()}} ingredientes en el sistema.
    </small>
```